# How to insert multiple records based on two columns of comma-separated values

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to create records based on multiple cells with comma delimited values.

Take This:

```
    Handle      |     Title    |   Color    |   Size     |     Price 
                |              |            |            |  (0-04/06-08)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jovani-JVN86957 |     Jovani   |  Black,    | 0, 02,     |   $199 (if size > 06  then +15)
                     JVN86957  | Red, White | 04, 06, 08 |
```

What I'm trying to do is have the Color and Size columns generate new records while including the Handle and Price(also if possible but not necessary to have the price changes based on the Size value ie: size 0-4 = $199 and size 6-8 = $219)

Turn to this:

```
Handle                Title         Color    Size  Price(0 04/06 08 +$15)

Jovani-JVN86957   Jovani-JVN86957   Black    0        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     Black    2        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     Black    4        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     Black    6        $199 +$15 = $214
Jovani-JVN86957                     Black    8        $199 +$15 = $214
Jovani-JVN86957                     Red      0        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     Red      2        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     Red      4        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     Red      6        $199 +$15 = $214
Jovani-JVN86957                     Red      8        $199 +$15 = $214
Jovani-JVN86957                     White    0        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     White    2        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     White    4        $199
Jovani-JVN86957                     White    6        $199 +$15 = $214
Jovani-JVN86957                     White    8        $199 +$15 = $214
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that the `if (size > 06 then +15)` condition is treated as if it were `if (size >= 06 then +15)` — only size 08 is strictly larger than 06, but you say you want sizes 6-8 to be given the more expensive price.  Also, your running text mentions 219, but the table mentions 214 — the latter is 199 + 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method that is a bit more of a brute force approach by using multiple loops.

```
Sub SplitEntries()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A5")

    'Copy over header
    Range("G1:K1").Value = Range("A1:E1").Value

    Dim sizeSplit As Variant
    Dim colorSplit As Variant
    Dim rowCntr As Integer: rowCntr = 2

    'Loop thru range
    For Each cell In rng
        Range("H" & rowCntr).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        'Get all the colors
        colorSplit = Split(cell.Offset(0, 2), ",")

        'Loop through each color
        For i = LBound(colorSplit) To UBound(colorSplit)
            'Get all the sizes
            sizeSplit = Split(cell.Offset(0, 3), ",")

            'Loop through each size
            For j = LBound(sizeSplit) To UBound(sizeSplit)
                Range("G" & rowCntr).Value = cell.Value
                Range("I" & rowCntr).Value = Trim(colorSplit(i))
                Range("J" & rowCntr).Value = Trim(sizeSplit(j))
                'Range("K" & rowCntr).Value = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value

                If Trim(sizeSplit(j)) < 6 Then
                   Range("K" & rowCntr).Value = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                Else
                   Range("K" & rowCntr).Value = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value + 15
                End If

                rowCntr = rowCntr + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

The starting data looks like this:

[image]

And the results are put in new columns like this:

[image]

Comment: Can we get rid of the price logic for the various sizes. I realized that some of my records have very different sizes so I would just like to simplify and just grab the value from the price column that I'll assign manually for that record.

Also I've applied this to a sheet with about 100 records with different color and size variants, and it's pulling some of the color/size/price as the title, and some odd behaviors.  I could of just applied the macro to the entire sheet incorrectly.  THis is what I changed:      Set rng = Range("A2:E259")

Comment: See the updated post for code modification to remove the price logic.  Try changing the range to `Set rng = Range("A2:A259")` as I'm only looking at the size of column `A` and assuming a fixed number of columns.  There are other ways to do it but it really depends on your layout.

Comment: can we make one more change to this.  It seems like I'm getting a better understanding of what needs to happen with the different prices based on the sizes.  

Can we add a logic to the prices for the various sizes.  Lets say if size is > 6 we want to add + $15 more.  I don't need the dollar signs.

Comment: You currently have two price values, are you wanting to add $15 to both and display $214/$234?

Comment: No, with the new price format I'll just have one price For each record, but when the sizes gets to be like 6 or greater it should add an extra $15 dollars.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I'm adding $15 too... could you give an example?

Comment: Forget about the two different $199/$219 prices.  There's going to only be one price for each record rows.  I've updated the tables in my original question.  Basically if the size > 6 if we can add $15 to the prices in the price column.

Comment: Okay, I updated the code to include logic for pricing.  I'm using the value in column E (assuming only 1 price is in cell) and adding 15 when the size is greater than or equal to 6.

Comment: You are a genius, sir.  I wish I was high enough rep to upvote this.